# bad flag delimiters on mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess mod_rewrite which should:

take `site.co.uk/text` and turn it into `site.co.uk/text` BUT working as: `site.co.uk/biz.php?name=text` , with the qualifiers it only effects strings after the `/` that are not a file or folder. My code is here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not an existing dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not an existing file
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)$ cottages.php?name=$1 [P,NC,QSA]
```

I get the error 500:

> public_html/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

Which seems to me to be *either* the flags `[P,NC,QSA]` OR the regex query?

I have rewritten the regex as `[a-zA-Z0-9]` but this has not changed the error. I have also removed individual and all flags but this has also not changed the error. commenting out the lines does remove the error. I think the error is in the `RewriteRule` but I also need to remove the conditions if removing (commenting out) the rule.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

P.s> I Hate htaccess Mod rewrite, it's a pain in the diddles!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
# not an existing dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# not an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ cottages.php?name=$1 [P,QSA]
```

Comments cannot follow `RewriteCond` on same line.

Comment: Aw, @anubhava cheers, you're really solving my htaccess issues today!! I'll accept you when I can (5mins). Interestingly I got the code from another solution on SO, with no indicator that comments could not be on the same line. I live and learn!

Comment: Looks like someone tried to be informative by putting code like comment but hey this is .htaccess :)